# Backquote String Interpolation

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

Is it possible to use lisp's macro to do string interpolation?

For instance, can I make a macro like this:

```
(defmacro test (a) `",a")
```

So that (test abc) returns "abc" as a string? I could probably cheat by quoting it and turning that quote into a string, but that doesn't work for arguments like "9:00" (without double quotes).

Comment: Try [`(symbol-name 'a)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_2.htm).

Comment: @Dan: That won't work for my example. '9:00 tries to look for a package called "9", which doesn't exist.

Comment: @iHuman You'll need to escape it. Eg. `'9\:00` or `'|9:00|`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lisp macros operate on arguments that have already been read by lisp's reader. Because of that a macro can't change how it's arguments are read, and if you pass an argument that will signal an error when you try to read it, e.g. `9:00` in `(test 9:00)`, the reader signals the error before the macro even starts to run.

The reader is also customizable. Not in a way that would let you read `9:00` as `"9:00"` in a straightforward manner, but for example you could write a short reader macro that read `@9:00` as either `"9:00"` or as a date object.

Edit: Something like this:

```
(defvar *arguments-rt* (copy-readtable ()))

(defun timestring-reader (stream char &optional count)
  (declare (ignore char count))
  (with-output-to-string (s)
    (loop repeat 4 do (write-char (read-char stream) s))))

(set-macro-character #\@ #'timestring-reader () *arguments-rt*)

(let ((*readtable* *arguments-rt*))
  (let ((args "dinner @9:00"))
    (with-input-from-string (stream args)
      (loop for arg = (read stream () ())
            while arg collect arg))))

-> (DINNER "9:00")
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason why I was trying to jump through hoops to make it  a string is because I was using read-from-string on a joined version of the command line arguments. This caused using double quotes to be a pain, because bash did not pass the quotes to lisp. '@' is not anything special in bash, so I am going to your idea.

Comment: @iHuman I added a quick example. Setting the reader macro in the fresh readtable (created with `copy-readtable`) and binding `*readtable*` locally prevents the change from having surprise effects in far off code.

Comment: If all you want to do is get the command line arguments in a stuctured form, take a look at all the command line parsers out there (or just use them).

Answer (score 3):

Backquoting, whether in a macro or not, won't do this:

```
[1]> (defmacro test (a) `",a")
TEST
[2]> (test oh-no)
",a"
```

What you can do is use [`format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm), as follows:

```
[3]> (defun interp (name) (format nil "Hi, my name is ~A" name))
INTERP
[4]> (interp "Steve")
"Hi, my name is Steve"
```

Comment: So I would have to use a string?

Comment: For `9:00`, yes you would. You wouldn't have to for some other symbols, but it's often a very good idea to use a string for this kind of data. See m-n's response for a better explanation of why that is.

Comment: Your question is "Is it possible to use lisp's macro to do string interpolation?"  Yes, you have to use a string for string interpolation. If the fantasy syntax `",a"` worked, it would be  a form of string manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

For string interpolation, see [`format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_format.htm). eg. `(format nil "~a" a)` does what you want. In [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) there are some [format recipes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html)

*quasiquote and unquote* only works for lists, not other sequences.

Macros are transformation of code.. It's not something that happens runtime. Eg. when you have code like `(my-macro x)` where `x` in runtime would be  a string, the macro only sees the symbol. It can't know what type it is at expansion time.